# resizing nodes to fit screen iPad pro

Tags: swift, screen, sprite

I have a background node which I am resizing to fit the screen. It works as expected on an iPad air but when on an iPad pro (of either size) the node size appears to be slightly bigger than the screen even though the size is reporting to be correct using

```
print(node.size.width, node.size.height)
```

The screen size is also reporting the correct size

```
print(main.screen.bounds.size)
```

and I am allowing for screen scale

```
print("screenscale", UIScreen.main.scale)
```

Although this is returning "2" on all the iPads (air and pro)

Comment: can you include a screenshot of what you're talking about and any other related info?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SKSpriteNode(texture: fileName, size: CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height))
```

It works for me as Im using a node for a rolling background.